# Windows cannot print from various apps

Tags: windows-10, printing

I have quite a problem with printing on my Win 10.
It is simple, the windows refuses to print from some apps.

So far, I am able to print just from Notepad, MS paint (and maybe some other basic apps). I can only frint from those apps, that uses this form:

[image]

From other apps, like Firefox, PSPad (advanced text editor) and so on, which are using for example this form, the print will NOT reach the printing device (virtual or physical):

[image]

I can not also print from my MS Office.

But I have also found, that my RJ textEd is able to print via its completely custom print form.

The problem is, that in applications, from which I can not print, I can not print at all. Nor via physical printer, but also if I choose some virtual printer like Microsoft Print to PDF, the file will not get created either.
Form those apps, the documents will not get stucked, in print tasks on taskbar too.

[image]

From apps, form which I can print, I can use any printer, physical or virtual without any problem.

The problem persists through several updates and even on MS forums noone could give me any solution.

So - anyone has encountered a similar issue and knows, how to solve this? (Note: System resintall is not the solution I am looking for, even I know, that would definitely solve this :) )

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tested running the application as Administrator to access the printer?

Comment: Hi, @DrMoishePippik thanks ... well, Yes, I have started thinking about very complicated scenarios, what all can be wrong with the system, that I have forgotten about the basic thing. But this really didnt come across my mind, because - what the hell, it is printing, why administrator rights for this??? But - as it seems to be, as admin, I can print, so I will add it as solved (or add it as answer so I can credit you) ... nest step will be to figure out, why my office (and other apps) requests admin rights for printing .... but that is another problem, so for now, thank you :)

Comment: see answer I've added. Glad that Admin works.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing as Administrator. If that works, check printer security settings:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and enter *devic*.
- Select Settings: *Device and Printers*.
- Right-click on *Printer properties* (not *Properties*, at the bottom).
- On the *Security* tab, allow specific users and/or groups to access it.

[image: Printer Security tab]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figured it up and there is more steps to do.

1) I have moved my TEMP folder via system variables. After that, there is a need to add extra rights to TEMP and TEMP/Low.

2) Then, there is a need of re-setting rights for each printer. BUT - rights in basic security form in Control Panels/ Devices and Printers/Printer properties/Security is NOT ENOUGH. You have to go to the ADVANCED. Then, my problem was, that even if I have set all the rights there, upon OK and reopening the advanced window, the rights went to their original setting. So there is a need to ADD even already existing group (E.g. Everyone) and set it correctly. Just after that it stops resetting upon advanced rights form closure.

[image]